# Adding more values on existing python dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and i am stuck while making a dictionary.. please help :)

**This is what I am starting with :**

```
dict = {}
dict['a']={'ra':7, 'dec':8}
dict['b']={'ra':3, 'dec':5}
```

**Everything perfect till now. I get :**

```
In [93]: dict
Out[93]: {'a': {'dec':8 , 'ra': 7}, 'b': {'dec': 5, 'ra': 3}}
```

**But now, if I want to add more things to key 'a' and i do :**

```
dict['a']={'dist':12}
```

**Then it erases the previous information of 'a' and what i get now is :**

```
In [93]: dict
Out[93]: {'a': {'dist':12}, 'b': {'dec': 5, 'ra': 3}}
```

**What i get want to have is :**

```
In [93]: dict
Out[93]: {'a': {'dec':8 , 'ra': 7, 'dist':12}, 'b': {'dec': 5, 'ra': 3}}
```

Can someone please help??

Comment: As a side note, don't use `dict` as a variable name, as it is already bound to the `dict` type.

Comment: this is a good tip :) will remember!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = {'ra':7, 'dec':8}
>>> d['b'] = {'ra':3, 'dec':5}
>>> d['a']['dist'] = 12
>>> d
{'a': {'dec': 8, 'dist': 12, 'ra': 7}, 'b': {'dec': 5, 'ra': 3}}
```

If you want to update dictionary from another dictionary, use [update()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting
>   existing keys.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = {'ra':7, 'dec':8}
>>> d['b'] = {'ra':3, 'dec':5}
>>> d['a'].update({'dist': 12})
>>> d
{'a': {'dec': 8, 'dist': 12, 'ra': 7}, 'b': {'dec': 5, 'ra': 3}}
```

Also, don't use `dict` as a variable name - it shadows built-in `dict` type. See what can possibly happen:

```
>>> dict(one=1)
{'one': 1}
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict(one=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
dict['a']['dist'] = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`dict['a'].update( {'dist': 12} )`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `{'dist':12}` to `dict['a']`, use the `update` method.

```
dict['a'].update( {'dist':12} )
```

This has the advantage of not needing to "break apart" the new dictionary to find which key(s) to insert into the target. Consider:

```
a = build_some_dictionary()
for k in a:
    dict['a'] = a[k]
```

vs.

```
dict['a'].update(a)
```